# DJANGO createsuperuser not working...TypeError: create_superuser() missing 1 required positional argument: 'username'

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am trying to create a RESTful API using Django and DRF. I have a User model which extends AbstractUser. I'm neither able to create normal users nor a superuser. For some reason, It says

When I run:

> python manage.py createsuperuser

I get the following error:

"TypeError: create_superuser() missing 1 required positional argument: 'username'"

Here's the models.py file:

```
import uuid
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.utils.encoding import python_2_unicode_compatible
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token
from api.fileupload.models import File


@python_2_unicode_compatible
class User(AbstractUser):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    profile_picture = models.ForeignKey(File, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, null=True, blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField('Email address', unique=True)
    name = models.CharField('Name', default='', max_length=255)
    phone_no = models.CharField('Phone Number', max_length=255, unique=True)
    company_name = models.CharField('Company Name', default='', max_length=255)
    address = models.CharField('Address', default='', max_length=255)
    address_coordinates = models.CharField('Address Coordinates', default='', max_length=255)
    country = models.CharField('Country', default='', max_length=255)
    pincode = models.CharField('Pincode', default='', max_length=255)
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email


@receiver(post_save, sender=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
def create_auth_token(sender, instance=None, created=False, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Token.objects.create_user(user=instance)
```

The serializers.py file:

```
from django.contrib.auth.password_validation import validate_password
from rest_framework import serializers

from .models import User
from api.fileupload.serializers import FileSerializer


class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    profile_picture = FileSerializer()

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = User.objects.create(**validated_data)
        return user

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        instance.name = validated_data.get('name', instance.name)
        instance.company_name = validated_data.get('company_name', instance.company_name)
        instance.address = validated_data.get('address', instance.address)
        instance.country = validated_data.get('country', instance.country)
        instance.pincode = validated_data.get('pincode', instance.pincode)
        instance.phone_no = validated_data.get('phone_no', instance.phone_no)
        instance.email = validated_data.get('email', instance.email)
        instance.profile_picture = validated_data.get('profile_picture', instance.profile_picture)
        instance.save()
        return instance

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('email',)
        model = User
        fields = (
            'id', 'password', 'email', 'name', 'phone_no', 'company_name', 'address', 'country', 'pincode', 'profile_picture',
        )
        extra_kwargs = {'password': {'write_only': True}}
```

The views.py file:

```
from rest_framework import viewsets, mixins
from .models import User
from .serializers import UserSerializer
class UserViewSet(mixins.RetrieveModelMixin,
                  mixins.ListModelMixin,
                  mixins.CreateModelMixin,
                  viewsets.GenericViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
```

Comment: Please provide the command which cause the error.

Comment: python manage.py createsuperuser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `createsuperuser` command, it will require you to input some required field, `USERNAME_FIELD` is a required field, and all fields inside `REQUIRED_FIELDS`. Your code set `REQUIRED_FIELDS=[]` so there is no required field, just need to add `email` and `password`.

But when `createsuperuser` has been called, it will call `create_superuser` method which require `username` field:

```
def create_superuser(self, username, email=None, password=None, **extra_fields):
```

so that your input data is not enough to pass the data into `create_superuser` method.

To solve this, you can simply just add `username` into `REQUIRED_FIELDS`:

```
REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username']
```

then `createsuperuser` will require you to add `username` field for `create_superuser` method.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks! This did work...but the create_user() is still not working it gives the following error:

`{"non_field_errors":["Unable to log in with provided credentials."]}`

Comment: I don't think it has something to do with `create_user`. That message is something about wrong credentials, wrong password..

Comment: But I'm trying to create a new user..so how will have wrong credentials

Comment: Yeah, I'm curious about that too. How you call `create_user` method @GoutamBSeervi? via view or via command too?

Comment: In the serializers create method

Comment: Did you copy the the error as a mistake? I don't think create_user method will cause that message @@..

Comment: Not sure if create_user() is causing the error..but yes when I send the payload...that is the response I get

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201035/discussion-between-toan-quoc-ho-and-goutam-b-seervi).